# Plotting time series with multicolor line in Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

This my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2020-07-01', end='2020-07-20', freq='d')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng))).cumsum()
df['Signal'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I would like to color the line according to the column "Signal", e.g. if Signal = 0 color the line blue, if Signal = 1, color the line orange.

I tried the following using seaborn, which is not what I want. I want to have one line with with 2 colors.

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="date", y="data", hue="Signal")
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try that [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib color line by "value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687414/matplotlib-color-line-by-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2020-07-01', end='2020-07-20', freq='d')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng))).cumsum()
df['Signal'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

sig_0 = np.ma.masked_where(df['Signal'] ==0, df['data'])
sig_1 = np.ma.masked_where(df['Signal'] ==1, df['data'])
plt.plot(df['date'], sig_0, df['date'], sig_1)
```

This will give you following plot.
[image]

The gaps correspond to the points where your signal values moves form 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.
you can fill those gaps with some other color by putting an additional plot command

```py
plt.plot(df['date'], df['data'], color='grey')
plt.plot(df['date'], sig_0, df['date'], sig_1)
```

Resulting Figure
[image]