# How to plot events in a day using matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a CSV that roughly looks like this:

```
start,end,activity
5:00AM,6:00AM, eating
6:15AM,7:00AM, work
7:00AM, 8:00AM, eating
etc. etc.
```

I've been trying to visualize this data in order.
I.e, ideally, I'd create a single line/rectangle that is 24 hours long, and then have different parts of the line/rectangle be colored for different activities.

I'm sure there are ways to do this using the low-level APIs, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with some sort of pre-defined chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting time series with multicolor line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169010/plotting-time-series-with-multicolor-line-in-python)

Comment: That's pretty close; although ideally I'd just have a flat line / a flat rectangle.

Comment: You can modify it according to your requirement.