# How to use categorical colour scheme in matplotlib with missing values?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want to make a scatter plot in python coloured by a categorical variable that handles and plots missing values for the categorical colour variable.

Using the iris dataset as an example

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

Seaborn can plot by colour:

```
sns.lmplot('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', hue='species', data=iris, fit_reg=False)
```

With a little more work so can matplotlib (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26139658))

```
colours = {'setosa':'skyblue', 'versicolor':'orangered', 'virginica':'forestgreen'}
plt.scatter(iris.sepal_length, iris.sepal_width, c=iris.species.apply(lambda x:colours[x]))
```

But neither will plot missing colours. If we set the species variable (which we use to colour the plot) to `np.nan` for one species seaborn doesn't plot those points and matplotlib won't plot anything.

```
iris.species[iris.species == 'setosa'] = np.nan

sns.lmplot('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', hue='species', data=iris, fit_reg=False)
iris.plot('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', kind="scatter", c=iris.species.apply(lambda x:colours[x]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution with seaborn but you can tweak the lambda function to work it in matplotlib. If the `species` is in your colour dictionary it looks the colour up there but if the `species` is null it return a novel colour.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#colour dictionary
colours = {'setosa':'skyblue', 'versicolor':'orangered', 'virginica':'forestgreen'}

col_convert = np.vectorize(lambda x: 'grey' if pd.isnull(x) else colours[x])

plt.scatter(iris.sepal_length, iris.sepal_width, c=col_convert(iris.species))
```

Comment: Yes, `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False` in Python.  I think you'll need to do `fillna("missing")` or something similar on your actual dataset.