# Plotting a multicolored scatter graph from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have a pandas dataframe called data, with two numerical columns (col1 and col2) and one categorical (col3)

I want to plot col1 and col2 against each other, but colour points by col3

I tried this:

```
plt.scatter(data["col1"],data["col2"],c=data["col3"])
```

which I expected to work but got an error.

Comment: Can you also add the error you got ?

Comment: is your col3 numerical data?

Comment: `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='col1', y='col2', hue='col3')`.

Comment: no - its strings

Comment: convert your strings to numerical values using a dictionary and then try plotting it again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139423/plot-different-color-for-different-categorical-levels-using-matplotlib