# How to assign a color for each unique value in a pandas Serie

Tags: pandas, plot, series

I have a timeserie of 1351 values embedded into a pandas dataframe with two columns:

- date
- value

[image: current plot]

I want to add a unique color for each year to have a result who looks like this:

[image: Desired plot]

I tried to create a series with all years and pass it to the `c` parameter:

`df.plot(x='date', y='value', figsize=(15, 10), c=df.date.dt.year.astype('category'));`

Unfortunately, I've got the error message:

```
1       2022
2       2022
3       2022
4       2022
        ... 
1346    2010
1347    2010
1348    2010
1349    2010
1350    2010
Name: date, Length: 1351, dtype: category
Categories (13, int64): [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, ..., 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022] is not a valid value for color
```

**How can I assign a unique color for each year without creating a color palette manually?**

I know you can use this trick with R how can I achieve it with python / pandas ?

Comment: can you provide enough code to set up a minimal example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965916/2901002